# Showing an error while downloading "Autopy" in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, autopy

While Installing autopy in python it shows an error which looks like this:

```
Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at 'D:\Python\python.exe'.
```

**I tried everything, I deleted my old interpreter and added a new one and did delete and reinstall pycharm and python, I also tried downloading old version of autopy but still the problem is not solved**

Comment: Can't you use virtual venv?

Answer (score 1):

You might have more than one Python installed on your system. You should check on Pycharm --> file> settings> project>project interpreter.

You should find the other Python instance on your system and change your interpreter to that one. If it does not appear in the list click on the button that looks like star in front of the project interpreter.

After changing the interpreter you should not receive that error anymore.

Comment: hey I don't know why it's like showing 2 interpreters and they both are same like exact same i tried switching between them but still nothing is happening

Answer (score 0):

Download Python 3.8 or lower
autopy does not work in upper versions

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).